# Checking props in callback method using jest

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, enzyme

I've started writting test cases in jest and I'm new to it. I've  a callback funtion with res as argument to it and shows props based on condition.

```
myModalCallback = (res) => {
    this.props.myCallBack ? this.props.myCallBack(res) : () => { };
  }
```

my test cases:

```
const myModalCallback = ({ res }) => (
expect(Filler.props().myCallBack).toBeDefined());
```

But I'm getting (res)/ not covered. Is there any way to test it?

Answer (score 0):

Since there was partial code in the question, I mocked myModalCallback and this.props, please take a look at the below test case. Tested and ran it on jest all test cases passing with 100% coverage.

```
const myModalCallback = function(res) {
  this.props.myCallBack ? this.props.myCallBack(res) : () => {};
};

describe("myModalCallback", function() {
  it("returns undefined when myCallback is not defined", () => {
    expect(myModalCallback.bind({ props: {} })()).toBeUndefined();
  });
  it("returns undefined when myCallback is not defined", () => {
    const myCallBack = jest.fn();
    myModalCallback.bind({ props: { myCallBack } })(1);
    expect(myCallBack).toHaveBeenCalled();
    expect(myCallBack.mock.calls[0][0]).toBe(1);
  });
});
```

Code sandbox link where this test runs and all cases are passing.
https://codesandbox.io/s/m5v24789rp

Comment: Did you run this test case. Because I tried it on code sandbox and it works. If you made some changes what were they?

Comment: I didnt make anychanges,do we have to run the application also while running the test case?

Comment: @HemaNandagopal no, you don't need to run the application.